# iOS collapsed TableViewCells are transparent

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a TableView with expandable cells.  When a cell is selected I change the height of the cell to show the rest of the content.  The problem is that when the cells are collapsed, they are transparent and all of the content is visible through the lower cells.  How can I make these cells opaque?

Comment: set cell background color as clearColor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem, it's not that the cell is transparent, it's that the subviews are visible outside the bounds of the cell. You can eliminate that by setting the clipsToBounds property for your cell to YES. You can do that in code, or in IB by selecting the "Clip Subviews" checkbox.